Autozero OPAMP design
I am trying to design an autozero ping-pong amplifier for a school project. I searched in books and on the internet for architectures, but all of them are so different that I don t know which is best.
I started implementing the simplest autozero opamp I found (in the picture), but I don t understand a few things

The inverting input of the opamp is always connected to the capacitor, what happens if I want to use the opamp in a buffer configuration, or other config that uses the inverting input
The output voltage equation is "Vo=A*Vin", my amplifier has 120dB gain, I don t know how to test the amplifier, if the output is always VDD because of the gain (the amplifier is a folded cascode with a class AB output stage, my mentor told me to implement this)
For the pin-pong amplifier in the second picture again, I don t understant how I can use this as an general purpose amplifier if the inverting output is always connected to ground (I can t use a differential input voltage)


This images are from "Witte, Kofi, Makinwa and Huijsing - Dynamic offset compensated CMOS amplifiers"
